# Write data come from concurrent requests to Kafka

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, elixir

I'm building an event collector, it will receive a http request like `http://collector.me/?uuid=abc123&product=D3F4&metric=view` then write request parameters to Apache Kafka topic, now I use Plug, Cowboy and [KafkaEx](https://github.com/kafkaex/kafka_ex).

```
defmodule Collector.Router do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts) do
    opts
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn = fetch_query_params(conn)
    KafkaEx.produce("test", 0, "#{inspect conn.query_params}")
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
    |> send_resp(200, "OK")
  end
end
```

AFAIK, Cowboy spawns a new process for each request, so I think write to Kafka in the `call` function is a proper way because it's easy to create hundreds of thousands of processes in Elixir. But I wonder if this is the right way to do? Do I need a queue before write to Kafka or something like that? My goal is handle as much concurrent requests as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using both kafka_ex and brod, and noticed that produce calls in brod are markedly faster - this may have been a bug when testing, but I'd advice for non-trivial use cases to look at both drivers and see what fits better. I'd advice to read the Cowboy code to remove the "AFA" from the "AFAIK", in that case you should be fine assuming that you want to wait for the result of the produce. 

For very high performance, try to minimize Kafka round trips - batch produces to individual brokers in separate servers employing async acks to the cowboy process.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Confluent Kafka REST Proxy because then you might not need to write any server side code.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Worst case is you might need to rewrite the incoming URL into a properly formatted HTTP POST with JSON data and the right HTTP header for Content-Type. This can be done with and application load balancer or a basic reverse Proxy like haproxy or nginx.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, actually I want to write a collector by myself to see how the performance of elixir. I'm building the data-pipeline, so I think I have to use java somewhere.

Comment: It's all open source and written in Java so maybe some ideas for you if you look at the code.